# Use of explicit commit in transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, commit, rollback

Is there any difference in adding `explicit commit` in my `transaction` than auto commit.

```
CREATE TABLE #test (test_col INT)
```

**With explicit COMMIT**

```
INSERT #test
VALUES (11)

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN DELETE_TRAN

    DELETE FROM #test

    COMMIT TRAN DELETE_TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN DELETE_TRAN

    SELECT ERRORMESSAGE = Error_message()
END CATCH

SELECT *
FROM   #test
```

**Without explicit COMMIT**

```
INSERT #test
VALUES (11)

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN DELETE_TRAN

    DELETE FROM #test
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN DELETE_TRAN

    SELECT ERRORMESSAGE = Error_message()
END CATCH

SELECT *
FROM   #test
```

Here both does the same thing. Can anyone tell is there any difference or advantage one over the another.

Comment: Good question.  This might be a better fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @destination-data - Should I have to post the same question in the above mentioned site well ?

Comment: No, I was told off for doing this! Apparently it's bad form. If you want you can flag the question, as off topic - wrong site. The mods will then move it.

Comment: @destination-data flagged it successfully

Answer (score 3):

The main functional difference I could see would be that by using the explicit COMMIT in your first example you are making sure that the table (temp table in this case) is unlocked for the SELECT statement at the end. Whereas in your second example, the SELECT would be blocked for other users, unless they were performing dirty reads (ie. WITH (NOLOCK), etc), until the implicit COMMIT is triggered.

Due to the fact that you're using a temp table it's not necessarily a big deal but if you were to change that to an actual table then you would have a difference in how long that table is locked due to the open TRAN on it. This would mean that concurrent calls would block for much longer and stack up behind each other. Or in the case of dirty reads, the other connections would not see your changes yet.

It's also a good standard practice to explicitly close any TRAN you open in SQL so that you are not relying on the caller to attempt to COMMIT the TRAN. Keep in mind that if the connection to SQL is closed and the TRAN has no COMMIT then the TRAN automatically gets a ROLLBACK instead.

Comment: Exactly was looking for this answer. Thanks a ton

Comment: In my original scenario it was not temp table

Answer (score -1):

Implicit Commit is slower than Explicit Commit, we can turn ON or OFF the implicit depends upon our requirement, for further details you can see this link:[SQL Server – performance and other stories](http://sqltouch.blogspot.ae/2013/05/writelog-waittype-implicit-vs-explicit.html)

Comment: Is there any functional difference ?

Comment: Is there any way that the above query(**Without explicit COMMIT**) causes any error like this `The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction. `. I got this error when executing one procedure which never throwed any error like this for past 1 year

Comment: @ask_Overflow, then add the commit. I would suspect a database patch was applied and that is why you never got the error before. However, it is a POOR  practice to open a transaction without explicitly closing it both through a commit or a possible rollback.